# What is my applicative functor not working with Ramda's ap?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, applicative

I am trying to learn how to use  applicative functors in javascript and came across the `ap` method. I am trying to use it to combine three arrays like so:

```
const products = ['teeshirt', 'sweater']
const options = ['large', 'medium', 'small']
const colors = ['red', 'black']
```

So as per the [documentation](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#ap) I am trying out this:

```
const buildMerch = product => option => color =>`${product}-${option}-${color}`

const merchandise = R.ap([buildMerch], [products, options, colors])
```

But this is giving me back three functions:

```
[function (option) {
  return function (color) {
    return product + '-' + option + '-' + color;
  };
}, function (option) {
  return function (color) {
    return product + '-' + option + '-' + color;
  };
}, function (option) {
  return function (color) {
    return product + '-' + option + '-' + color;
  };
}]
```

...instead of the combined result of the arrays that I expect:

```
["teeshirt- large-red", "teeshirt- large-black", "teeshirt- medium-red", "teeshirt- medium-black", "teeshirt- small-red", "teeshirt- small-black", "sweater- large-red", "sweater- large-black", "sweater- medium-red", "sweater- medium-black", "sweater- small-red", "sweater- small-black"]
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Here is a jsbin with the issue: https://jsbin.com/fohuriy/14/edit?js,console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ap` applies a list of functions to a list of values, per the documentation. Your function `buildMerch` has the following "type":

```
buildMerch :: String -> String -> String -> String
```

The simplest kind of `ap` is `map`: for any applicative functor, we get:

```
pure f <*> a
  ======
map f a
```

For arrays, `pure` is `x => [x]`. So,

```
R.ap([buildMerch], [foo, bar, baz])
  ======
R.map(buildMerch, [foo, bar, baz])
```

By mapping `buildMerch` over the argument list, we are partially applying it to the arrays in question. The expression that does what you want is:

```
const merchandise = R.ap(R.ap(R.map(buildMerch, products), options), colors);
```

First, we map `buildMerch` over the product array. This gives us an array of functions taking two arguments: `[String -> String -> String]`. Then, we use `R.ap` to combine that with `options :: [String]`, which applies each function in the first array with each argument in the `options` array. Now we have `[String -> String]`, and finally we `R.ap` that with `colors` to get the final array of strings that you want.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve this problem is to add `ap` to the native javascript Array. This way you're essentially turning Array into an applicative functor, you don't need a library, and it works with the same interface as any other applicative functor you may want to use.

```
// add ap
Array.prototype.ap = function(anotherArray) {
  return this.map(el =>
    anotherArray.map(el)
  ).flatten();
};
```

This relies on flatten (or 'join').

```
// add flatten
Array.prototype.flatten = function() {
  let results = [];
  this.forEach(subArray => {
    subArray.forEach(item => {
      results.push(item);
    });
  });
  return results;
};
```

Now:

```
const products = ['teeshirt', 'sweater'];
const options = ['large', 'medium', 'small'];
const colors = ['red', 'black'];
const buildMerch = product => option => color =>`${product}-${option}-${color}`;

const merchandise = products.map(buildMerch).ap(options).ap(colors);
```

Now you could also Lift all three:

```
const liftA3 = (fn, functor1, functor2, functor3) =>
  functor1.map(fn).ap(functor2).ap(functor3);

liftA3(buildMerch, products, options, colors) // also returns merchandise
```

Answer (score 1):

[AP](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#ap) applies a list of functions to a list of values. In your case, you will invoke `buildMerch` with every element in your specified array, which is `products`, then `options` and after that with `colors`, and not with every combination within your arrays. This does not match to your method signature, where you expect three arguments.